# WinForms: Cannot get ValidateChildren to raise Validating event of a child control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

In a Windows Form application I have a Form with a UserControl that contains a child control.  I have an event handler for the child control's Validating event.  On the parent UserControl I call the `ValidateChildren()` method.  But the event handler for the child control's Validating event does not run.  The CausesValidation property is set to true on both the parent UserControl and the child control.  Is there any reason why the Validating event handler would not run?

The child control is a custom control derived from `Panel`.  It contains two RadioButton controls, both of which have their CausesValidation property set to true.

Comment: No repro.  You need to post a sample project that exhibits this problem on a file sharing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  The control was not raising the Validating event because it was not selectable.  A Panel control is not by default selectable nor are controls derived from Panel (See [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol.aspx)).  So in the UserControl's constructor I called `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);`.  Now it raises the Validating event.